# Regression of two variables depending on a third

Tags: regression

Suppose you have a table with three variables: A, B, and C. The rows are the values of the variables at different points in time. You want to determine if A predicts B. One possibility is computing a lagged regression of B on A. Look at p-values for statistical significance and R^2 for % explained variance.

So now suppose I suspect that the R^2 of B regressed on A depends on the values of C. How should I investigate this? What if I suspect that this relationship (between C and how good the regression of B on A is) is nonlinear?

I'm leaving it quite general because I'm hopefully looking for general answers.

Comment: I suggest making a 3D scatterplot of A, B, and C and performing visual inspection from different rotation angles to see if any relationship is apparent. If you do not have a software tool for making 3D scatterplots you can use my open source  web site's 3D Data Characterizer at http://zunzun.com/CharacterizeData/3/ which can make them for you.